# Yammer embed not showing post images

Tags: embed, yammer

I am embedding a Yammer group feed using the method outlined here,https://help.yammer.com/entries/21262512-Embed-a-feed but I am not seeing any posted images in the embedded feed. Has anyone else encountered this before? Please note I am using the free version.

**SCRIPTS**

```
<script data-app-id="fyB2pTcfL36Y80py8RTj6F" src="https://assets.yammer.com/platform/yam.js"></script>

<script>
    yam.connect.embedFeed({
        container: "#design-ideas",
        network: "myYammerFeed",
        feedType: "group",
        feedId: "1053789"});
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
.fleft{ float:left;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <h1>Design Ideas</h1>
    <div id="design-ideas" class="fleft"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. I was floating the divs where the feed was displaying and changing this caused the images to not appear. This is troublesome if you want to have multiple divs each showing the feeds from your different Yammer groups.